# How create range filter by several fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have Mongo collection

```
{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 1 }
{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

with compound index by A, B and C. Now I want to query records greater than `{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }`. Result should be

```
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

I want to use exactly range query (not sort + skip). Is it possible?

**Update:** 
Sorry, my example is little accurate.

1. Result isn't greater, but greater or equals.
2. I want to query to whole field set A, B and C, not individually.

Thx @BlakesSeven for his advice.

Here is another example:

Greater than `{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 }` is

```
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

**Update 2:**
Sorry for my little unclear question. I try to explain one more time:
I have collection sorted by several fields (A, B and C). I use [compound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) `{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 1 }`. Sorted collection:

```
1: { A: 1, B: 1, C: 1 }
2: { A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 }
3: { A: 1, B: 2, C: 1 }
4: { A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }
5: { A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }
6: { A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 }
7: { A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
8: { A: 2, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

I have some record (e.g. 5) and I want to query records which are greater in this order (6, 7, 8).

Comment: I will note that that the required result is not "greater than" in any of the respects you have asked for but is instead "greater than or equal to". This is also a notably "abstract" question that likely has nothing to do with your real use case. To get "real" answers, present your "real" use case so that the answer can be clearly provided that suits your real needs and avoids arguing with respondants in comments.

Comment: So A, B or C needs to be greater? Is that correct?

Comment: @ThomasBormans, no. All records are sorted by A, B and C. And I want to query records from specific position (see example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo has [min()](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.min/#cursor.min) feature which uses exactly in this case. 
So for collection

```
{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 1 }
{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 1, C: 2 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
{ A: 2, B: 2, C: 2 }
```

Query for "greater or equals" `{ A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 }` is

```
db.collection.find().sort({A: 1, B: 1, C: 1}).min({ A: 1, B: 1, C: 2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky but possible

```
 var a = 1;
 var b = 2
 var c = 3;
 var value = a*100+b*10+c;
 db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,A:1,B:1,C:1,D:{$add:[{$multiply:[100,"$A"]},{$multiply:[10,"
$B"]},"$C"]}}},{$match:{D:{$gt:value}}}]);
```